# I added jobs like this: but why I get childJob duplicated?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

```
public class Job
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long? JobId { get; set; }

    public Job ParentJob { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Job> ChildJobs { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var child = new Job { Name = "ChildJob" };
var parent = new Job { Name = "ParentJob", ChildJobs = new List<Job>()};
parent.ChildJobs.Add(child);
_context.Jobs.Add(parent);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

I added jobs like this: but why I get childJob duplicated?

[ { "id": 1, "jobId": null, "parentJob": null, "childJobs": [ { "id": 2, "jobId": 1, "childJobs": null, "name": "ChildJob" } ], "name": "ParentJob" }, { "id": 2, "jobId": 1, "parentJob": { "id": 1, "jobId": null, "parentJob": null, "childJobs": [], "name": "ParentJob" }, "childJobs": null, "name": "ChildJob" } ]

Comment: your parent object has the child object in its childjobs variable. 
When you copy that object you are copying both

Comment: The jobs aren't duplicated. It's the JSON serializer that duplicates them because of the mutual references.

Comment: Ok, Neil, How should I copy them? there is something wrong here, it is returning childjob as same level of parentjob, not right.

Comment: The child job *is* a Job! In the database you just create two jobs that happen to be related. You should tell where this JSON bit comes from so we can help you shape it the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks Gert for you clarification. That actually makes sense.I was doing this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio  The json comes from the get method. Originally I wanted to do widget with list of child widgets.